# ALGOLIA - Numeric Filters with OR conditio

Tags: reactjs, algolia, instantsearch.js, instantsearch, react-instantsearch

I have around 2557378 records in ALGOLIA. i am trying to apply few conditions with numericFilters

[image]

I need to fetch all a values b values and c values

[image]

I used Filter condition as below:

```
{
    "numericFilters": [
        "A>50 OR B > 0  OR C > 0"
    ]
}
```

The results for each part showed in below:

[image]

The `OR` condition not work fine. What can be the issue?

Already posted in algolia community :
https://discourse.algolia.com/t/numeric-filters/17350?u=thamira.weerakoon

> Note: I am not expect A and B and C as below

[image]

> Summery:
>
> I need to fetch all A value B values and C values via react InstantSearch

Comment: In your combined condition you're looking for `A > 0 OR B > 50`, but individually you are checking `A > 50` and `B > 0`, which I believe is a typo

Comment: AND condition not fulfill this

Comment: The condition should be `C > 0 OR B > 0 OR A > 50`, you swapped the condition between `A` and `B` by accident

Comment: @HaoWu I don't get you. can you elaborate it. My undemanding is C > 0 OR B > 0 OR A > 50 or A > 0 OR B > 0 OR C > 50 need to return same count

Comment: I'm not sure how your data look like but those are completly different conditions. Normally `A > 50 OR B > 0` = `B > 0 OR A > 50`, but `A > 0 OR B > 50` ≠ `A > 50 OR B > 0`

Comment: @HaoWu Thank you. I got the point. yes that us typo issue

Comment: can you also try `numericFilters: [ [ "A>50", "B > 0",  "C > 0"] ]`

Comment: btw are you not getting results that are A>50 only with your current filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read from the usage notes on [numericFilters](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/numericFilters/#usage-notes)

- **No boolean operators**: you can’t use boolean operators like AND and OR.
- **Multiple filters**: if you specify multiple filters, they’re interpreted as a conjunction (AND). If you want to use a disjunction (OR), use a nested array.

you may have to try the [array notation mentioned here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/facetFilters/#usage-notes).

i.e you may have to use it like

```js
{
    numericFilters: [[ "A>50", "B>0",  "C>0"]]
}
```

I tested with the OR conditions on a dummy index I created and it seems to short circuit after the first OR condition for example `"A>50 OR B>0  OR C>0"` gave me the hits with A>50 only and changing the order to something like `"C>0 OR A>50 OR B>0"` gave me C>0 only